# How to 'query' woocommerce tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I just want to sum up all 'total_sales' in 'wc_order_stats' table for completed orders. Just like this:
`SELECT SUM(total_sales) FROM wc_order_stats WHERE status = 'wc-completed'`

Can I use WP_Query? How?

I have tried this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'lp_course',
  'meta_key'  => 'total_sales',
);
```

but 'total_sales' is not a result data.

What would you do?
Thanks

Comment: You can use `WPDB` Class as follows: `global $wpdb; $total_sales = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(total_sales) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_order_stats WHERE status = 'wc-completed'");` then for display use `echo __("Total sales") . ': ' . $total_sales . '<br>';`… That should work.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!

Comment: If you want I can added it as an answer (it could be useful for others).